# How to fix "'list' object has no attribute 'values'" when reading JSON file

Tags: python, json, attributeerror

```
[{
    'original_block': '213.158.64.0/19',
    'transferred_blocks': '213.158.64.0/19',
    'from': 'REGISTER.IT S.P.A.',
    'to': 'REGISTER S.P.A.',
    'date': '01/07/2019',
    'transferType': 'MERGER_OR_ACQUISITION',
    }, {
    'original_block': '5.154.240.0/23',
    'transferred_blocks': '5.154.240.0/24',
    'from': 'NAV COMMUNICATIONS SRL',
    'to': 'uPress Inc',
    'date': '01/07/2019',
    'transferType': 'POLICY',
    }, {
    'original_block': '78.159.136.0/21',
    'transferred_blocks': '78.159.140.0/22',
    'from': 'Telecom Aset Ltd',
    'to': 'Aryaka Networks Inc.',
    'date': '01/07/2019',
    'transferType': 'POLICY',
    }, {
    'original_block': '81.88.48.0/20',
    'transferred_blocks': '81.88.48.0/20',
    'from': 'REGISTER.IT S.P.A.',
    'to': 'REGISTER S.P.A.',
    'date': '01/07/2019',
    'transferType': 'MERGER_OR_ACQUISITION',
    }]
```

I have a list of IP transfers information that I loaded from a JSON file. I want to extract some values from the JSON file (dictionary) but I keep getting `'list' object has no attribute 'values'`.

```
import json

with open ('iplist.json','r') as t:

    d = json.load(t)

address = [item['original_block'] for d_ in d.values() for item in d_]

print(address)
```

I get

```
'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I expect to see

```
address = ['213.158.64.0/19', '5.154.240.0/23', '78.159.136.0/21', '81.88.48.0/20']
```

Comment: `address = [item['original_block'] for item in d]`

Comment: it worked, thanks. What was my error please?

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a list of dictionaries, each of which has a `original_block` key.

just do this:

```py
d = [{'original_block': '213.158.64.0/19', 'transferred_blocks': '213.158.64.0/19', 'from': 'REGISTER.IT S.P.A.', 'to': 'REGISTER S.P.A.', 'date': '01/07/2019', 'transferType': 'MERGER_OR_ACQUISITION'}, {'original_block': '5.154.240.0/23', 'transferred_blocks': '5.154.240.0/24', 'from': 'NAV COMMUNICATIONS SRL', 'to': 'uPress Inc', 'date': '01/07/2019', 'transferType': 'POLICY'}, 
{'original_block': '78.159.136.0/21', 'transferred_blocks': '78.159.140.0/22', 'from': 'Telecom Aset Ltd', 'to': 'Aryaka Networks Inc.', 'date': '01/07/2019', 'transferType': 'POLICY'}, 
{'original_block': '81.88.48.0/20', 'transferred_blocks': '81.88.48.0/20', 'from': 'REGISTER.IT S.P.A.', 'to': 'REGISTER S.P.A.', 'date': '01/07/2019', 'transferType': 'MERGER_OR_ACQUISITION'}]

address = [item['original_block'] for item in d]

print(address)
```

Output:

```
['213.158.64.0/19', '5.154.240.0/23', '78.159.136.0/21', '81.88.48.0/20']
```